# Linear regression, finding slope in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regression

I'm trying to find the slope of a dataset that has DATETIME as the x axis, and a number on the y axis.

I've tried the a number of approaches, and nothing will match the slope of the line when I plug the data into Excel, it's off by multiple orders of magnitude.

This is what I have right now, but it's giving me a slope of -1.13e-13 instead of -0.008

```
SELECT (SUM((x-xBar)*(y-yBar)))/(SUM((x-xBar))*SUM((x-xBar)))) as slope
from (select unix_timestamp(date) as x, 
  (select avg(unix_timestamp(date)) from datatable) as xBar, 
   value as y, 
   (select avg(value) from datatable)  as yBar  from datatable) as d;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

#### Update:

I've also tried

`SELECT effortId,
( COUNT(*)*SUM(unix_timestamp(date)*value) -SUM(unix_timestamp(date))*SUM(value) ) /
(COUNT(*)*SUM(unix_timestamp(date)^2)-SUM(unix_timestamp(date))^2) AS Slope
FROM datatable;`

and get a completely different answer (-0.0019), is this more accurate? Anyone know?

Comment: have you worked out each sub select to see which one is producing a 0?

Comment: Yeah, I put the wrong SQL up (it was from a few back), I've edited it to be what I use now

Now I get -1.3 e-13

Answer (score 0):

What are the X units?  You'll probably have to convert the time values explicitly to what you expect, whether it is seconds, hours, or days.

Comment: @Jenn:  sure.  But what do you expect for the calculated slope units?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure. I think statistically, it should be value per time. Specifically, a DATETIME, if that's what excel/open office does.

Comment: Y units per time, yes.  But Y units per second, Y units per minute, Y units per hour, Y units per day (which is Excel's time I believe), Y units per month, Y units per year?

Comment: I think with the unix_timestamp it becomes Y units per second, but I think what I need is Y units per day.