# MySQL slope (trend) of single field (line of best fit)

Tags: mysql, select, trend

I have a simple table called LOGENTRY with fields called "DATE" and "COST". Example:

```
+--------------+-------+
| DATE         | COST  |
+--------------+-------+
| MAY 1 2013   | 0.8   |
| SEP 1 2013   | 0.4   |
| NOV 1 2013   | 0.6   |
| DEC 1 2013   | 0.2   |
+--------------+-------+
```

I would like to find the slope of the COST field over time (a range of rows selected), resulting in
SLOPE=-0.00216    (This is equivalent to Excel's SLOPE function, aka linear regression).

Is there a simple way to SELECT the slope of COST?  If I do the math in the calling language (php) I can find slope as:

```
SLOPE =  (N * Sum_XY - Sum_X * Sum_Y)/(N * Sum_X2 - Sum_X * Sum_X);
```

I saw some similar questions posted but they are more complex.  I'm trying to strip this example down to the simplest situation - so I can understand the answer :)  Here's as close as I got...but MYSQL complains about the syntax near: 
'float)) AS Sum_X, SUM(CAST(LOGENTRY.DATE as float) * CAST(LOGENTRY.DATE'

```
SELECT 
  COUNT( * ) AS N, 
  SUM( CAST( LOGENTRY.DATE AS FLOAT ) ) AS Sum_X, 
  SUM( CAST( LOGENTRY.DATE AS FLOAT ) * CAST( LOGENTRY.DATE AS FLOAT ) ) AS Sum_X2, 
  SUM( LOGENTRY.COST ) AS Sum_Y, SUM( LOGENTRY.COST * LOGENTRY.COST ) AS Sum_Y2, 
  SUM( CAST( LOGENTRY.DATE AS FLOAT ) * LOGENTRY.COST ) AS Sum_XY
FROM LOGENTRY
```

Comment: with this information no one can answer. When ever you post a question please post sample data , structure and desired output

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084761/how-to-calculate-the-slope-in-sql

Comment: I saw posting 9084761 but it is more complicated (additional field KEYWORD).  I'm trying to keep it simple so I and others can understand it better.

Comment: Do you desperately need it done within MySQL?  Most likely a lot easier in whatever is receiving the data.

Comment: Data is being returned to PHP.  I *thought* it was always more efficient to do it in the SQL

Comment: Well, it is if the data quantity is huge, otherwise perhaps not.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400440/linear-regression-finding-slope-in-mysql

Comment: Put parentheses around the sub-select in the FROM clause, and a comma after before it (to separate the tables, or use a JOIN).

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/601fa5/9 -- the slope result shows as 0 I imagine due to mantissa underflow, needs to be in a double.  Hence why I added the numerator and denominator to the output.  Though no quicker than doing what you have done in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that MySQL cannot cast a date as float (as per the other examples in stackoverflow).  Perhaps the other examples refer to another database.  So by converting dates to unix_timestamps I am able to get an answer...with the final calculation in PHP.  If this is WRONG...please post and I will remove answer...

```
SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS N,
        SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LOGENTRY.DATE)) AS Sum_X,
        SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LOGENTRY.DATE) * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LOGENTRY.DATE)) AS Sum_X2,
        SUM(LOGENTRY.COST) AS Sum_Y,
        SUM(LOGENTRY.COST*LOGENTRY.COST) AS Sum_Y2,
        SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LOGENTRY.DATE) * LOGENTRY.COST) AS Sum_XY
    FROM LOGENTRY
```

Comment: That's not too bad, though check your data to make sure you're getting a good answer out of it.